# Rotate object: How to start rotation by the last radian value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, rotation

I have this function which I like to extend, so the current rotation of an image will get considered.

The current behavior is that whenever I start to rotate the image by the mouse-cursor, it resets first to 0 rad, so if the image is rotated to 90 degrees first, it will jump to 0 on the next attempt to rotate the image.

I want it to start from the last radian value. I'm bad at math, would be nice if someone could help me out on this one.

```
Coordinate = [x,y]
Center = [x,y]
Extent = [minX, minY, maxX, maxY]

private get angleDelta(): number {

    if (this.isDragging) {
        return 0;
    }

    const extent = this.object.getExtent();
    const cursor = this.getCursorCoordinates();

    if (!extent || !cursor) {
        return 0;
    }

    const center = getCenter(extent);

    return getAngle(center, cursor) - getAngle(center, this.startCoordinate)
}


function getAngle(start: Coordinate, end: Coordinate): number {
    return Math.atan2(start[1] - end[1], start[0] - end[0]);
}
```

Comment: You have to add current radians

Comment: yes, you stock the current angle at the end of a rotation to reuse it in the next one1.